# how to create a dataset for multi-output regression with sliding window approach

Tags: python, tensorflow, regression, data-generation

I want to build normal DNN model, I have huge data with X_train= 8000000x7 and y_train=8000000x2.
How to create a dataset with sliding window of 100 data points to feed the neural network.

If I use a customized dataset using following code, I have a problem of allocation due to large dataset.

```
def data_set(x_data, y_data, num_steps=160):
    X, y = list(), list()
    # Loop of the entire data set
    for i in range(x_data.shape[0]):
        # compute a new (sliding window) index
        end_ix = i + num_steps
        # if index is larger than the size of the dataset, we stop
        if end_ix >= x_data.shape[0]:
            break
        # Get a sequence of data for x
        seq_X = x_data[i:end_ix]
        # Get only the last element of the sequency for y
        seq_y = y_data[end_ix]
        # Append the list with sequencies
        X.append(seq_X)
        y.append(seq_y)
    # Make final arrays
    x_array = np.array(X)
    y_array = np.array(y)
    return x_array, y_array
```

So, in order to avoid this is there any dataset generator I can use with sliding window for feeding into DNN.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Use `tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((X_train, y_train)).batch(BATCH_SIZE)`

Comment: @vijayachandranmariappan But I want to use stride =1, so that it moves through the dataset. How can do that? Any suggestion

Comment: @V.M
could you please have a look at this question and give some suggestion
[1]:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74458620/why-predicted-values-changes-everytime-the-lstm-model-runs-with-same-hyperparame

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `dataset.window` method to achieve that.

```
dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((X_train, y_train))
stride = 1
dataset = dataset.window(batch_size, shift=batch_size-stride, drop_remainder=True)
```

Comment: with batch_size=100, shift will be 99(100-1), but I want a window size of 160 so that 0 to 160 is one window and next 1-161 and so on.

Comment: I need to use this dataset as an input to cnn model

Comment: `dataset = dataset.window(batch_size, shift=stride, drop_remainder=True)` You need to adjust the `shift` parameter.